# tsc and lite-server error with angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular

So I am following a tutorial online and when he runs his program for the first time it works with out problems. But when I run mine it gives me this error. So what I did was googled it and of course i didn't have tsc and lite-server installed so I did 'npm install -g tsc lite-server'. ran 'npm start' again and still the same error. So then I went to the github repo for the tutorial I copied and pasted the package.json just in case I made typo or something silly yet still no good. What else might I be able to try? and I did do an npm install for all the dependencies. [image: Error I am getting] [image: package.json file]

Comment: After the copy & paste of the **package.json** did you delete the **node_modules** folder? If not, try to delete it and then run `npm install` again.

Comment: Yes forgot to mention that I did delete the **node_modules** and re-ran **npm install** and still the error happens.